Pre-biased transistor vs normal transistor for digital logic
I am building a breakout-board for a Quectel LC760Z GNSS module which requires the RESET and BOOT pins to be controlled by an open-collector circuit.
The reference design includes the following circuit but without explicit examples for the components:

I want to (optionally) include the transistor(s) on my board in case I can only have a push-pull pin available on my MCU.
However, I am not really familiar with transistor selection and I am not sure if the symbol calls for a pre-biased transistor or just a normal transistor and if I need to include biasing-resistors myself.
The equivalent circuit of a pre-biased NPN-transistor array like the DDC143TU-7-F looks right, but I have no idea how to select the resistors.


The pre-biased transistor is just a way to save board space and BOM lines. You can use a transistor and two resistors, the end result will be exactly the same.
If you're building a prototype, it's more convenient to pick parts from your stock.
Assuming the RESET line is held high with a usual value pullup resistor (>10k), the transistor will have to sink much less than 1mA to pull it down. Assuming current gain of 10 to keep it saturated, and 3V3 drive, this gives a base current of 100µA, so a base resistor around 27 kOhms. The value isn't critical. 10k will also work fine.
As for the pull down resistor on the base, it is not absolutely necessary. If your MCU resets with pins set to pullup, and you don't want the transistor to turn on when this occurs, then you need a pulldown resistor stronger than the MCU's pullups. But if you want to reset the module at power-up anyway, then you don't need a pulldown.
If the module's RESET pin uses the same logic levels as your MCU, you can also drive it from a MCU GPIO pin.
I guess the reason they tell you to use a transistor is the RESET pin might goe to a chip working at a lower voltage than 3V3, so it would be damaged by receiving 3V3 from a MCU GPIO. In this case the transistor is required, unless you trust your software enough to be certain the GPIO will always behave as open drain...

Yes the data sheet example clearly has a "digital" or "pre-biased" transistor symbol.
You can of course select any transistor you like and add suitable resistors for it. Or buy a single "digital" transistor, but usually you don't see them.
You could also just use a MOSFET transistor as it requires only one resistor to be on the safe side.
Or you can simply switch the MCU pin as output and input while the output state is kept low, so you don't need a special open-drain pin. Depending on your MCU, all pins might be capable of being configured as open-drain outputs.

Thanks for the answer! As this is a breakout board I want to be on the safe side and have the option to populate the transistor, even though I agree that normally I will be able to use or emulate the behavior directly from my MCU.
